# How to make Debug emit hex values in no_std code?

Tags: rust, rust-no-std

I'm making a bare metal application in Rust. I can easily make any given struct print its debug information, but I'd like some of them to print some of their values in hex.

For example:

```
impl core::fmt::Debug for Task {
    fn fmt(&self, fmt: &mut fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> fmt::Result {
        fmt.debug_struct("Task")
            // ...
            .field("SP", &self.context.sp)
            .field("KSP", &self.context.ksp)
            // ...
            .finish()
    }
}
```

I cannot figure out how to make `sp` and `ksp` (both `i64`) print as hexadecimal numbers. My first thought was to somehow use the `format!` macro, but since I'm using `#![no_std]`, I don't have access to it.

How can I make the debug output to print these values in hex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`format_args!()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/macro.format_args.html) macro. It is the source of all formatting machinery, but does not allocate and thus available in `core`:

```rust
impl core::fmt::Debug for Task {
    fn fmt(&self, fmt: &mut fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> fmt::Result {
        fmt.debug_struct("Task")
            // ...
            .field("SP", &format_args!("{:X}", self.context.sp))
            .field("KSP", &format_args!("{:X}", self.context.ksp))
            // ...
            .finish()
    }
}
```